# Check if an IP is connected to a specific port on a Java server

Tags: java, server, connection, port, minecraft

Creating a Minecraft server that shares the same server as what our RTC server is using.

Players will be connecting to the Minecraft server's port AND the RTC server's port.
I want to check to see if the player is connected to both of those ports on my server.

How would I go about this?

Comment: Just `Google` `Check open ports linux or windows`, you will find many good answers.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use netstat to identify connections to the server and then cross-check the IP addresses.